# code to read-in floating variables from a textfile containing more than one line

Tags: c++, text

In c++ how would I read a text file containing 3 float variables not as string types, but as float variable types for re-use by a program.

I was trying to use fscanf function and having results of it only reading in the first line of the file.  How do I tell it to use delimiters such as \n end of line and have it continue to process the rest of the file?

Thanks.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h> //Include math functions
#include <iostream> //Stream to allow input/output
#include <fstream> //Stream class to read/write files

using namespace std;
string line = "0.0";
char str [80];
float f;
FILE * pFile;

int main () { 
    pFile = fopen ("C:\\Users\\Brian\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CppApplication_2\\init_temps.txt","r"‌​);
    fscanf (pFile, "%f", &f);
    cout << f;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: `fscanf` DOES skip whitespace characters (including `'\n'`)

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Do you want to allow your three numbers to be separated by newlines?  Or do you want to force your program to read the three numbers from a single line, and detect if the line contains less than three numbers?

Comment: give me a second trying to provide clear example.

Comment: include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>    //Include math functions
#include <iostream>  //Stream to allow input/output
#include <fstream>   //Stream class to read/write files

using namespace std;

string line = "0.0";
char str [80];
float f;
FILE * pFile;


int main ()  {
pFile = fopen ("C:\\Users\\Brian\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CppApplication_2\\init_temps.txt","r");
fscanf (pFile, "%f", &f);
cout << f;
return 0;
}

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, it seems you are only reading the first number. You should iterate 3 times:

```
int i;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    fscanf(pFile, "%f", &f);
    cout << f << endl;
}
```

or better yet check for *fscanf()*'s return value to better decide if you've read it all.

On another note, you should learn to use local variables instead of global variables, unless there's really a need to.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

floats.text

```
5.5
2.2
1.1
```

read.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  float sum = 0;
  ifstream myfile ("floats.text");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      sum += ::atof(line.c_str());
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  cout << sum << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

result

```
./a.out
>> 8.8
```

Comment: does getline only return strings?

Comment: I dont understand sum += ::atof(line.c_str());  What is this doing?

Comment: I dont care about summing them, just storing them.

Comment: How would i assign the values in the file to variables?

Comment: `getline` does return a whole line from the file as a string.  `atof(line.c_str())` returns the float represented by the string `line`.  The `.c_str()` is needed because atof takes a char*, not a c++ string.   To store in a variable simply do `my_var = atof(line.c_str())`.

Comment: @BrianMcCall `::atof(const char*)` is a function that takes a C-style-string (`char*`) and converts it to a float. The `::` part is to ensure that the global namespace is used for that function. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator for that part.)

Comment: Would you like to store the numbers in memory or in a file or db?